# why did all of the events of the 5 terminator movies get split into 3 timelines

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-genisys

the events of The Terminator 1984 and Terminator 2: judgment day 1991 is now timeline 1  then they blew up cyberdine in 1995 and created timeline 2 where judgment day is now 2004 not 1997 then the events of terminator 3 and salvation took place then in terminator genysis they follow events of the 1st terminator movie but there are some changes like

> Upon arriving in 1984, Skynet's T-800 is disabled by Sarah and a reprogrammed T-800 Guardian  sent from an unknown origin to protect her when she was nine years old; Sarah has nicknamed the T-800 "Pops". Kyle arrives a short time later and is immediately attacked by a T-1000 Sarah and the Guardian join Kyle and destroy the T-1000 using acid. It's revealed that Sarah and the Guardian have constructed a makeshift time machine similar to Skynet's, and Sarah plans to travel to 1997 to prevent Skynet from becoming self-aware. Realizing the timeline has been altered, Kyle is convinced that the future has changed due to the warning he received in his childhood vision. He persuades Sarah to travel to 2017 instead to stop Skynet. sarah raised by pops in 1973, visions of kyle reeses kid self, Matt smith is skynet, john conner is a terminator

which created timeline 3 and erased the 1st 2 timelines for good and the events of the 4 terminator movies never happened ever so im really confused why count the events of The Terminator (1984)  Terminator 2: Judgment Day (1991)   Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines (2003)   Terminator Salvation (2009)
Terminator Genisys (2015) happend in 1 timeline and i woun"t be confused? why did all of the events of the 5 terminator movies get split into 3 timelines ?

Comment: What makes you think that there's only three timelines? Also, what makes you think that whoever wrote the Wikipedia entry you're quoting has any better handle on this than you do?

Comment: becuase i found out in a video explaining the timeline

Answer (score 2):

The video you've linked was apparently written by someone who really didn't understand the films. There are **far more than three timelines** and far more inconsistency then they're giving credit for.

Terminator (1) is best described as the *Prime* timeline. In it, Skynet becomes self-aware *on its own* and initiates Judgement day. After a brief war with the humans, it realises it's lost and sends back a Terminator to kill the head of the Human Resistance, not realising that in doing so, it's actually creating a predestination paradox in which it's complicit in John's birth.

Terminator 2 opens in the Prime timeline (in which John and his mother have been working to undermine Skynet and to prepare him for war) but Skynet once again becomes the instrument of its own destruction by forcing John to send a T-800 into the past along with detailed plans on how to stop Skynet from being built. This creates a new timeline in which Judgement day doesn't happen at all (Timeline 2).

Unfortunately, Skynet isn't an idiot and has already sent back a T-X (which arrives in Timeline 2) to make sure that John's lieutenants are killed and to jump-start its own creation. This works and it creates a third timeline in which Skynet once again becomes self-aware and initiates Judgement Day. (Timeline 3).

T4 (Salvation) takes place shortly after Judgement Day. The events occur within Timeline 3 and can largely be ignored.

T5 (Genisys) then plays merry hell with the timelines. When the Kyle from Timeline 3 travels back into the past he discovers that the Resistance from a future timeline (Timeline 5?) have sent a Terminator even farther back into the past to protect Sarah when she was a child, thus creating an alternate Prime timeline (Timeline 4)

[image]

Simple really.

Comment: But I still don't get it why did the events of all 5 terminator movies get split into 5 timelines why count they be 1 timeline

Comment: The past remains the same is terminator or back to the future and why

Comment: so why did the movies get split into 5 timelines why count they be 1 timeline i need a better explanation timelines are confusing for me it is not simple really

Comment: Think of it like a train that lays its own tracks in front of it. Our heroes are on the train and can only travel along one set of rails. When they use a time machine they can jump back along the track and change the train's direction in the past. Each time that happens, a new track (a new timeline) is created.

Comment: but why did the events of Terminator Genisys (2015) erased the events of The Terminator (1984) Terminator 2: Judgment Day (1991) Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines (2003) Terminator Salvation (2009) and those events never happend ever

Comment: @AndrewCasali Because they completely changed the situation in 1984, meaning the events that spawned from the Prime timeline (basically everything in the first four movies) couldn't possibly have happened.

Comment: so the prime timeline everything in the first four movies got erased and never happend ever why! the events of all 5 movies should of  been in just one  timeline why were the events of the first 4 movies erased? why wasn't th events of the 5 movies be in just one timeline

Comment: In the Prime timeline, Sarah Connor in 1984 is a helpless waitress and she's saved by Kyle Reese. Everything that happens in the first four movies starts from that point and is built on that key point. If that's not the case then none of it can logically happen, it's just logically impossible. I don't know how else to explain that.

Comment: I'm just really confused on why all 5 terminator movies are split into 5 time lines and couldn't be just one timeline and why  the last 4 movies were erased from the timeline  forever

Comment: Because people are (doing) **different things** at the **same point in time** in all five of them. Sarah Connor can't both be a helpless waitress and be a total badass in 1984 at the same time, that requires there to be at least two separate timelines. Judgement Day can't both happen in 1997 and not happen in 1997, so that also requires there to be at least two separate timelines, though these two timelines only exist as an extension of the "Sarah is a helpless waitress in 1984" timeline, so that makes at least three timelines.

Comment: How is there  no indication on what happens to the old obsolete timelines

Comment: When you change the past, it creates a new timeline. That's just the way it works in the Terminator films. You just have to accept that in the same way that you accept that time travel is possible.

Comment: thats why i asked why don't the events of the last 4 movies exist any more

Comment: @AndrewCasali - They don't exist because they went further back in time and changed created a brand new timeline where the events of the first four films never took place.

Comment: why did they went further back in time and changed created a brand new timeline where the events of the first four films never took place

Comment: Are you asking why the people who made the film chose to do this or why the Resistance chose to do this?

Comment: either one i dont care

Comment: @AndrewCasali The answer to "why does time travel in such-and-such a fictional universe work in such-and-such a way?" is usually just "**because it does**". That's how that particular fictional universe is set up. Like Richard says, you just have to accept it even if you don't fully understand it. Time travel is hard.

Comment: so the events of the last 4 movies happen in 1 timeline and genysis is a another timeline

Comment: @andrewcasali - That's certainly one way of looking at it.

Comment: what event split the 4 movies into 1 timeline and the events of genysis is a another timeline why is it like that

Comment: You're looking for logical answers where none probably exist. The out-of-universe explanation is that every time the producers want to make a new Terminator movie they have to come up with some semi-plausible way of involving the same characters in yet another dramatic time-travel plot. Each movie has made some attempt to meld its plot into the overall Terminator story, but the very nature of it's time travel basis means that each movie invalidates parts of the preceding movies (or renders them completely redundant). As @Randal'Thor said, the reason it works that way is just "because it does".

Comment: how do i watch the movies timeline wise